# Создание REST API на базе MVC

Tags: php, rest

Здравствуйте!

Есть задача, написать REST API которое будет выполнять такие функции: получить​ ​пост​ ​по​ ​id, создать пост, изменить пост, удалить пост.

Так вот, мне немного не понятно, как в REST происходит создание, обновление и удаление. Я знаю, что есть методы GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, но мне не понятно как с ними работать в PHP.

Создание поста и обновление делается через форму? А как же вызвать метод DELETE? Как вообще url может понять, что books/id - это, скажем, получить инфу о книге, но и books/id - это удалить книгу? Где надо прописывать эти методы?
пожалуйста, если не сложно, объясните с примерами.

Comment: а `<form method="DELETE">` написать нельзя что ли? _Форма_ это частный случай инструмента отправки запроса с помощью браузера. Чтобы определить с помощью какого вызыван запрос, обратитесь к `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

Comment: Я не понимаю как этот метод указать в PHP. Что это именно DELETE, a не GET.

Comment: давайте начнем сначала, на базе какого MVC вы собираетесь создавать API ? Если у вас имеется MVC, то видимо, как минимум есть контроллера, в методом `public function books($id){... }` вот внутри его вы и можете проверить, значение `$_SERVER[...].`, чтобы понять, каким методом отправить запрос

Comment: MVC самописный. Мне вот просто с роутами не понятно. В файле с роутами я прописываю  books/id  дважды. Один роут идет на то, чтобы получить данные о книге, а второй - чтобы удалить. Допустим у меня есть кнопка delete рядом с каждой книгой в списке. Кнопка - это ссылка на books/id. Вот как этот скрипт поймет, что мне надо удалить книгу, а не прочесть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитайте более подробно о том, что такое REST. Если очень грубо и очень кратко: каждый метод HTTP запроса здесь отвечает за конкретное действие.

Комментарий под вопросом отвечает на него, как мне кажется. Действительно, для получения метода запроса Вы можете просто обратиться к $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].

Если Вам непонятно, каким образом получить, в таком случае, данные запроса (привычный $_GET или $_POST тут уже не подойдет), то здесь все неколько сложнее, однако, примеров даже на SO полно.

Вот пример с англоязычной версии, в котором проверяется тип запроса и выполняется соответствующее действие:

```
public function initialize(...) 
{
  ... code ...

  $request_vars = array();
  if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']))
  {
    switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
    {
      case 'PUT':
        if ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded' === $this->getContentType())
        {
          parse_str($this->getContent(), $request_vars );
        }
        break;

      case 'DELETE':
        if ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded' === $this->getContentType())
        {
          parse_str($this->getContent(), $request_vars );
        }
        break;
    }
  ... more code ...
}

public function getContent()
{
  if (null === $this->content)
  {
    if (0 === strlen(trim($this->content = file_get_contents('php://input'))))
    {
      $this->content = false;
    }
  }

  return $this->content;
}
```

А вообще, существует множество готовых решений для разработки REST API.